# How can I show all interfaces in a project/package in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to show a list of all interface definitions of a project or package in Eclipse (Java)? E.g. something like a filter for the Package Explorer, or a special View. An eclipse plug-in would also be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the Java browsing perspective? That has lot of views and customizations to allow quick and easy browsing of Java code

Comment: It worked. In the "Types" view of the "Java browsing" perspective I added a filter which only shows Interfaces.

Thanks a lot for the hint, I forgot that perspective!